# Where to find the output of system.out with gradle in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

It is not the run window and the console does not appear in the gradle window. I want to view the output of system.out.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to <kbd>View</kbd> --><kbd>Tools Window</kbd>--><kbd>Run</kbd>.
Or you can just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> ,it will open run tab at the bottom of IDE .